# Diagnose a RAM usage spike on page load

Tags: out-of-memory, profiling, pageload, airconsole

When we launch our game in the AirConsole, the RAM usage jumps really high and we get an "Out of memory" error. The only way to actually test the game is to upload a Development build with exceptions enabled and the WebGL Memory Size set to 2047. That's the only scenario, when the game doesn't crash.

We used Chrome to monitor the RAM. When we launch the game in the AirConsole, the RAM gets heavily loaded (2 GB or so) and after the game loads, the RAM usage becomes much lower (about 1 GB).

I think it is directly connected to the huge JS file that we get, when we make a WebGL build, but that's only a guess.

How can we diagnose the problem and lower the RAM usage?

Comment: I shifted the question's focus to "what are the tools for diagnosing memory" because "how to reduce memory consumption" is too broad for SO - it cannot be answered in anything less than a book (and for your specific case, an answer would require your full code).

Comment: You may instead rather wish to ask if there's a higher level tool specifically for WebGL or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to profile memory usage by the page with the tools a browser provides - just like you would do for a desktop application.

- [JavaScript Memory Profiling - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)
- [MemoryBug Firefox extension](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Memorybug)
- [Diagnosing memory problems in your webpages (Windows) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

They vary in sophistication, but are basically the same as in every other garbage-collected environment. They can be divided into two basic types:

- rough data: general dynamics, snapshots (incl. on events), usage by entities (DOM,JS,plugins) - identify main hogs
- fine data: GC statistics, object links - locate specific culprits